# load: failed to read matrix from file

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm try to load a some variables ( matrix,number ...) from a file .dat,  but when I try to load I get the mistake *load: failed to read matrix from file*.

this is the main file

```vb
function resultado = batallaNaval()
   init();
end

function resultado =init()
  load historial.dat;
  jugadas = historial() 
end
```

The code the file historial.dat is:

```vb
a=[1 1 ;2 1; 3  0; 4  7];
numberBoats= 5;
```

which is the correct form to load the variables?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this instead

```
load('historial.dat', '-mat');
```

This tells MATLAB it's in the .mat file format, even though it doesn't have the right extension.